# Throwing an error while parsing json response in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, parsing, response

I am trying to parse a simple json response.

{"GetOptionsResult":[{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"290/200 HP V8 Engine","OptionCode":"1008852"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"290/225 HP V8 Engine","OptionCode":"1007059"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"343/235 HP V8 Engine","OptionCode":"1008853"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"343/280 HP V8 Engine","OptionCode":"1005857"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"360/315 HP V8 Engine","OptionCode":"1008854"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"390/315 HP V8 Engine","OptionCode":"1008054"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"4 Speed Transmission","OptionCode":"1007678"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"6 Cylinder Engine","OptionCode":"1006735"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"AMX Big Bad Package","OptionCode":"1005249"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"Amx/javelin SST Go Package 390","OptionCode":"1007251"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"Factory Air Conditioning","OptionCode":"1006048"},{"OptionGroup":null,"OptionGroupID":0,"OptionDisplayName":"Javelin SST Big Bad Package","OptionCode":"1008355"}]}

And below is my POJO class to parse the above json.

```
class ClassicCarsOptionsModel {
  List<GetOptionsResult>? getOptionsResult;

  ClassicCarsOptionsModel({this.getOptionsResult});

  ClassicCarsOptionsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['GetOptionsResult'] != null) {
      getOptionsResult = <GetOptionsResult>[];
      json['GetOptionsResult'].map((v) {
        getOptionsResult!.add(new GetOptionsResult.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.getOptionsResult != null) {
      data['GetOptionsResult'] =
          this.getOptionsResult!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class GetOptionsResult {
  String? optionGroup;
  int? optionGroupID;
  String? optionDisplayName;
  String? optionCode;

  GetOptionsResult(
      {this.optionGroup,
      this.optionGroupID,
      this.optionDisplayName,
      this.optionCode});

  GetOptionsResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    optionGroup = json['OptionGroup'];
    optionGroupID = json['OptionGroupID'];
    optionDisplayName = json['OptionDisplayName'];
    optionCode = json['OptionCode'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['OptionGroup'] = this.optionGroup;
    data['OptionGroupID'] = this.optionGroupID;
    data['OptionDisplayName'] = this.optionDisplayName;
    data['OptionCode'] = this.optionCode;
    return data;
  }
}
```

It is throwing an error and I am unable to parse a data.

I have tried to debug into POJO class but it kept throwing an error? What could be the issue? How can I track where exactly and why it is crashing?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I am not sure how can I track the error in POJO class but it is throwing me in a catch block.

Comment: What `catch` block?  Don't unconditionally swallow errors.  There isn't much anybody can do to help you without seeing what the error is or without seeing a minimal, complete example that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print exception in Catch block and also see the stacktrace during the API request. As well if you use dio then use interceptor to track the activity of request and response.